# Basic question about how this C code is working

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int get_pos_int(void);

int main(void) {
    int i = get_pos_int();
    printf("You entered the positive Integer of %i\n", i);
}

int get_pos_int(void) {
    int n;
    do {
        n = get_int("Insert a positive Integer: ");    
    }
    while(n < 1);
    return n;
}
```

So of course this is just a simple program to test for if a number entered is a number above 0. Out of interest I decided to make this small change to see if it was semantically still correct.

```
int main(void) {
    get_pos_int();
    printf("You entered the positive Integer of %i\n", get_pos_int());
}
```

When running the program with this change, if I input the number '1' it returns me back to the prompt to type an integer, then if I type 1 again it returns 'You entered the positive Integer of 1'

I was just wondering if you could explain what the behaviour is causing this, I like to know why things are working the way they are and it interested me how removing the function being stored in a variable made it behave this way.

Comment: You get odd behaviour because you call `get_pos_int()` twice with the revised code, and each time it demands input.  Call it once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your description of what happens, I'm assuming you meant `get_pos_int()` in your `printf`.

`int i = get_pos_int()` stores the return value of the function, not the function itself. So when you made your change, you call the function but discard the value it returns. The function then gets called again in your `printf` statement. The function being called twice is why you have to enter 1 twice.

Comment: Meanwhile OP edited the code `printf("...", get_pos_int)`->`printf("...", get_pos_int())` making previous comments look stupid.

Comment: Yes sir, you are correct I missed the brackets in my original post, thank you for still answering correctly and helping me understand this behaviour. Thank you.